# Is it possible for PHP to follow a URL?

Tags: php, url, redirect

Is it possible for PHP to take a URL, wait for the redirects to go through, and then fetch the url of the page it's on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    $cr = curl_init("http://example.com"); 
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
    curl_exec($cr); 
    $info = curl_getinfo($cr);
    echo "url=".$info["url"];
```

Comment: Also, to add serg's answer... you might want `curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);` to set the max number of redirects to allow.

Comment: @brianreavis: What is the benefit of MaxRedirs?

Comment: @AliGajani Performance / not bogging down your server. Each redirect will be a new HTTP request... MAXREDIRS allows you to limit it to something you deem sane for your application. A third-party site could theoretically have an infinite number of redirects.

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

-j

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a wget / curl wrapper.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php